# Bouncing ball animation: need to leave a trail

Tags: animation, canvas, simulation, game-physics

Here is a canvas animation of a bouncing ball. http://jsfiddle.net/eakA4/

My problem is that I would like the ball to leave a trail, ie a line that marks out where the ball has been in the past.

The code that determines the position of the ball is:

```
  (function drawFrame () {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame, canvas);
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    //theta = Math.atan2(mouse.y-ball.y,mouse.x-ball.x);

    ball.x += vx;
    ball.y += vy;
    if (ball.x > canvas.width - ball.radius) {
        ball.x = canvas.width - ball.radius;
        vx *= -1;
    } else if (ball.x < 0 + ball.radius){
        ball.x = 0 + ball.radius
        vx *= -1;
    }
    if (ball.y > canvas.height - ball.radius){
        ball.y = canvas.height - ball.radius
        vy *= -1;
    } else if (ball.y < 0 + ball.radius){
        ball.y = 0 + ball.radius;
        vy *= -1;
    }
    ball.draw(context);
  }());
```

My problem is that because I'm using clearRect(), any path I try to draw is being wiped out. What I could do is keep adding ball.x and ball.y coords into an array then using the canvas lineTo() to link all these points each frame, but that would reach a large number of points very quickly.

Can anybody suggest a way of doing this?

Comment: Here's an outline of what I would try:Save the last every 10th (or 25th, or whatever looks good) sets of x,y coordinates you've used in a circular buffer. Then when you paint, render those old locations from the oldest to the newest with opacity close to 0 on the first and then gradually increasing to 100 for your current location.

Comment: Hmm thanks but I'd really quite like a complete history.

Answer (score 3):

Saw now that you want a line as trail not just trails as in motion-blur.

Updated fiddle for this:
http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/eakA4/3/

Add a new canvas on top where you can draw the lines to. This way you avoid clearing and keep rack of everything.

<strike>You can simply replace this line:</strike>

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

with this:

```
var tmp = context.fillStyle; //backup fillstyle

context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)';
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

context.fillStyle = tmp;
```

The alpha channel value determines how much trails you'll get (less is more).

Updated example:
http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/eakA4/2/

(PS: I also fixed it so it works with Firefox - see `requestAnimationFrame` polyfill in code).